# Text not showing below images in IE

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, text

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xWPyH/)

My question is, why is the headline text not showing under the thumbnails in IE (8 and earlier). Works fine in all other browsers.

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbsGrid">
    <div class= "thumbs">
        <a href="http://youtu.be/A30XhK8Vtmg">
            <img src="http://www.jillmedinger.com/NCPIE/images/thumbs/shadowed/recoverythumb.png"id="1.thumb"/>
        </a> 
        <h4><a href="http://youtu.be/A30XhK8Vtmg">Ben</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class= "thumbs">
        <img src="http://www.jillmedinger.com/NCPIE/images/thumbs/shadowed/recoverythumb.png" id="2.thumb"/> 
        <h4><a href="/NCPIE/resonator.html"> The Resonator</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class= "thumbs">
        <a href="/NCPIE/re.html">
            <img src="images/thumbs/door2/friendsThumbs.png"id="3.thumb"/>
        </a> 
        <h4><a href="/NCPIE/re.html">RE-Covery</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class= "thumbs">
        <a href="/NCPIE/divedeeper2.html">
            <img src="images/thumbs/door2/divedeeper2Thumb.png"id="5.thumb"/>
        </a>  
        <h4><a href="/NCPIE/divedeeper2.html"> Dive Deeper </a></h4>
    </div>
    <!--thumbsGrid close-->     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbs {
    float:left;
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    margin-right:12px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
#thumbsGrid {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    min-height:216px;
    margin-left:110px;
    border:0;
    padding-right:40px;
    background: black;
}
.thumbs h4 a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

And here it is live: www.jillmedinger.com/NCPIE/door2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the `filter` on the `.thumbs`. The easiest resolution is to set `position: relative` to the `h4` as [this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/xWPyH/1/).